# Pandas copy from one sheet to another based on row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

There are many posts similar, and they have solutions, but they are for much more complicated data/questions, which makes it irrelevant and I fail to understand it all-together.  I want to make this simple.

Below is the data from "New_File.csv"

```
Name,Rating
Dr_Banner,8.6
Tony_Stark,9.6
Steve_Rogers,8.1
Mary_Jane,6.1
Peter_Parker,8.4
Natasha_Romanoff,9.2
```

Here is the data from "Old_File.csv", to which I need to update the Rating column, which does not have the "Name" column in the same order as the "new_file.csv

```
# Please note that the Rating column is empty and needs to filled from the "New_File.csv"..

Name,Movies,Rating
Tony_Stark,11,
Peter_Parker,5,
Steve_Rogers,8,
Natasha_Romanoff,10,
Dr_Banner,9,
Mary_Jane,2,
```

I have tried this code below to achieve it.  But obviously it does not do anything, and I am totally confused.

```
import pandas as pd
New_File = pd.read_csv("New_File.csv")
Old_File = pd.read_csv("Old_File.csv")

character_names = ["Dr_Banner", "Tony_Stark", "Steve_Rogers", "Mary_Jane", "Peter_Parker", "Natasha_Romanoff"]

for names in character_names:
    # Find the value to Update from New_File
    filter1 = New_File.loc[New_File['Name'] == names]
    filter2 = filter1["Rating"]
    # Find the value to Update in Old_File
    filter3 = (Old_File['Name'] == names)
    # Updating the Value
    Old_File.loc[filter3, 'Rating'] = filter2
    # Saving the file
    Old_File.to_csv("Old_File.csv", index=False)
```

I need to update the "rating column, based on the "Names" column, as they are shuffled. Please help.

Comment: Question regarding the format of Old_File.csv.  As shown, you have three column headings "Name", "Movies", "Rating", the data for this file is formatted so the Movies Column will contain the rating value is this correct? Or should your data rows be configured like:  ```Tony_Stark,,11```

Comment: @itprorh66 , thanks for asking.. Actually, the "Old_File.csv" has the second column for "Number of Movies" and then the "Rating"... So the final data should be like Tony_Stark,11,9.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
New = pd.read_csv(r"C:/users/k_sego/New.csv", sep=",")
Old = pd.read_csv(r"C:/users/k_sego/Old.csv", sep=",")
Old = New.merge(Old, on="Name", how='inner')
Old =Old.drop(['Rating_y'],axis=1)
Old = Old.rename(columns={'Rating_x':'Rating'})
```

which gives the updated Old file

```
              Name  Rating  Movies
0         Dr_Banner     8.6       9
1        Tony_Stark     9.6      11
2      Steve_Rogers     8.1       8
3         Mary_Jane     6.1       2
4      Peter_Parker     8.4       5
5  Natasha_Romanoff     9.2      10
```

And then to_csv

```
Old.to_csv("Old_File.csv", index=False)
```

**EDIT**

To keep the order of columns, change the order of the merge

```
New = pd.read_csv(r"C:/users/k_sego/New.csv", sep=",")
Old = pd.read_csv(r"C:/users/k_sego/Old.csv", sep=",")
Old = Old.merge(New, on="Name", how='inner')
Old =Old.drop(['Rating_x'],axis=1)
Old = Old.rename(columns={'Rating_y':'Rating'})
```

which returns

```
               Name  Movies  Rating
0        Tony_Stark      11     9.6
1      Peter_Parker       5     8.4
2      Steve_Rogers       8     8.1
3  Natasha_Romanoff      10     9.2
4         Dr_Banner       9     8.6
5         Mary_Jane       2     6.1
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, but the output data shown has data which is wrong.. Sorry, but the Name and Movies column don't match anymore from original data..

Comment: thanks for the solution Serge, it works great... but one problem is that it is changing the column order... is there any possibility that the column order remains the same please....(My original data has more than 15 columns in the new and old file, and the order is important plsss)

Comment: Yes, change the order of the merge. See edit! Check, the solution as the accepted one.

Comment: Thanks soo much Serge, and yes it works!! :)